# how to use tilt to cache / precompile slim file in sinatra views

Tags: ruby, sinatra, tilt, slim-lang

Slim documentation says that the template/.slim file can be compiled and cached with tilt. I am using slim for the views in sinatra. How to precompile the file / is it possible to view the compiled file..
Also would it cache the precompiled file after the first call. should I do some setting for it in sinatra

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well, the Sinatra Readme is your friend. In :production all your views are compiled by default. Please also have a look at the Caching section in the Readme which will give you the different options.

Comment: there probably is a .slim dir somewhere